# How can be sum of demands value for each iteration in solution list[ ]?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested-loops

I have demand **dictionary** as shown below and solution list and I used nested technique to sum the demand in each iteration in the solution `list []` , I have get some results, but I tried lots of time to sum demands of solution list as `(2-24, 28-5 , 8-3,7-4 and 18-6)` according to their demand in the dictionary

```
demand= {1: 0, 2: 5, 3: 23, 4: 14, 5: 13, 6: 8, 7: 18, 8: 19, 9: 10, 10: 18, 11: 20, 12: 5, 13: 9, 14: 23, 15: 9, 16: 18, 17: 10, 18: 24, 19: 13, 20: 14, 21: 8, 22: 10, 23: 19, 24: 14, 25: 13, 26: 14, 27: 2, 28: 23, 29: 15, 30: 8, 31: 20, 32: 24, 33: 3}

solution=[[2, 22, 15, 20, 12, 19, 29, 24], [28, 26, 31, 11, 13, 5], [8, 27, 9, 14, 33, 21, 3], [7, 25, 23, 16, 17, 4], [18, 10, 30, 32, 6]]
```

code:

```
for i in solution:
    print(i)
    for j in i:
        print(demand[j])
```

results:

```
[2, 22, 15, 20, 12, 19, 29, 24]
5
10
9
14
5
13
15
14
[28, 26, 31, 11, 13, 5]
23
14
20
20
9
13
[8, 27, 9, 14, 33, 21, 3]
19
2
10
23
3
8
23
[7, 25, 23, 16, 17, 4]
18
13
19
18
10
14
[18, 10, 30, 32, 6]
24
18
8
24
8
```

my question how can sum demands in **1st iteration(5 10 9 14 5 13 15 14)** and I need put the sum in same location also  sum of demands in **second iteration(23-13 )** and a same way with other values.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you explain what you're trying to do better I have no idea what's being asked or what you did to get those numbers, or what the demands or solutions mean

Comment: the solution list its my final results I got it from our algorithm and there is a demand for every single node inside the solution list so based on elements order in the solution I need to calculate their demands (quantity or features nodes)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly, After trying many time I got the best results as follow:
code:
demand= {1: 0, 2: 5, 3: 23, 4: 14, 5: 13, 6: 8, 7: 18, 8: 19, 9: 10, 10: 18, 11: 20, 12: 5, 13: 9, 14: 23, 15: 9, 16: 18, 17: 10, 18: 24, 19: 13, 20: 14, 21: 8, 22: 10, 23: 19, 24: 14, 25: 13, 26: 14, 27: 2, 28: 23, 29: 15, 30: 8, 31: 20, 32: 24, 33: 3}
solution=[[2, 22, 15, 20, 12, 19, 29, 24], [28, 26, 31, 11, 13, 5], [8, 27, 9, 14, 33, 21, 3], [7, 25, 23, 16, 17, 4], [18, 10, 30, 32, 6]]
for i in solution:
print(i)
s=[]
for j in i:
print(demand[j])
s.append(demand[j])
print("sum demand",sum(s))

Answer:
[2, 22, 15, 20, 12, 19, 29, 24]
5
10
9
14
5
13
15
14
sum demand 85
[28, 26, 31, 11, 13, 5]
23
14
20
20
9
13
sum demand 99
[8, 27, 9, 14, 33, 21, 3]
19
2
10
23
3
8
23
sum demand 88
[7, 25, 23, 16, 17, 4]
18
13
19
18
10
14
sum demand 92
[18, 10, 30, 32, 6]
24
18
8
24
8
sum demand 82

Comment: please anyone organised the solution it will be a pleasure